# How to join adjacent elements in a list with a string in between?

Tags: python

I am starting on my Python journey and am doing some exercises to get the hang of it all. One question is really giving me troubles as I do not understand how to complete it.

Given a list with an even number of integers, join adjacent elements using '-' and print each pair.
So it will be that this is given:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

and the output needs to be:

```
1-2
3-4
5-6
7-8
```

Now I have gotten as far as this, but have no idea what to do next:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
a1 = a[::2]
a2 = a[1::2]

duos = zip(a1, a2)
print(list(duos))
```

And this only gives me this as result:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

I feel like I am close and just missing one tiny step.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Build a lazy iterator:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> it = iter(a)
>>> print([f"{x}-{y}" for x,y in zip(it,it)])
['1-2', '3-4', '5-6', '7-8']
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep, very close indeed.

You can use a generator expression to form the pair strings without the intermediate variables, then `"\n".join` to make a single string out of the formatted pairs.

```
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> print("\n".join(f"{a}-{b}" for (a, b) in zip(numbers[::2], numbers[1::2])))
1-2
3-4
5-6
7-8
```

The more procedural version (that's functionally equivalent, but doesn't form a list, but just prints each pair) would be

```
for (a, b) in zip(numbers[::2], numbers[1::2]):
    print(f"{a}-{b}")
```

Answer (score 2):

Completing your work:

```
for x, y in duos:
    print(f'{x}-{y}')
```

(Note you need to do this *instead* of your `print(list(duos))`, otherwise that consumes the `zip` iterator and there's nothing left.)

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat fun<sup>[*]</sup> alternative, easily adapts to similar cases just by altering the string of ends:

```
from itertools import cycle

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

for x, end in zip(a, cycle('-\n')):
    print(x, end=end)
```

For example with `cycle('+-*\n')`, it would instead print this:

```
1+2-3*4
5+6-7*8
```

[*] Everything itertools is fun for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're indeed very close. Now just print each pair in duos on a separate line with a dash as separator:

```
for a,b in duos: print(a,b,sep="-")
```

Or you could do it all in one line using a combination of map, zip and join:

```
print(*map("-".join,zip(*[map(str,a)]*2)),sep="\n")
```